# tkinter Radiobutton string selector

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Some time ago I wrote a Python3 program to allow me to connect to one of a number of computers.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
import os

Computers = [
    'RaspberryPi3',
    'PiUbuntu',
    'Thylacoleo']

def sel():
    cmd = "open afp://" + Computers[var.get()] + ".local"
    os.system( cmd )

root = Tk()      # create tkinter object
root.title("Connect to Computer")   # give the window a title...
root.minsize(250, 100)
var = IntVar()
button=0

for cc in Computers:
    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text=cc, variable=var, value=button, command=sel)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )
    button += 1

root.mainloop()
```

This works, and I though it would be simple to adapt this, using a Dictionary to mount `nfs` shares.
Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work.

My previous effort returned an integer from each button. but this would not work with a Dictionary, and I wanted to get a string value returned.

```
Computers = {
    'RaspberryPi3': 'Pi3',
    'PiUbuntu': 'PiUbuntu',
    'Ubuntu-T': 'Thylaco'
    }

def sel():
    print("selection", tvar)
    selection = "You selected the option " + tvar

root = Tk()      # create tkinter object
root.title("Connect to Computer")   # give the window a title...
root.minsize(250, 100)
# var = IntVar()
# tvar = StringVar()
tvar = str()
button=0

for cc in list(Computers.keys()):
#     R1 = Radiobutton(root, text=cc, variable=var, value=button, command=sel)
    R1 = Radiobutton(root, text=cc, variable=tvar, value=cc, command=sel)
#   R1 = Radiobutton(root, text=cc, textvariable=tvar, command=sel)
    R1.pack( anchor = W )

root.mainloop()
```

I know I could make a list, and use an integer, but I am trying to understand how to get a string returned. I have read the documentation, and looked at lots of links, but not discovered any relevant examples.

`tvar = StringVar()` results in an error:-

```
TypeError: must be str, not StringVar
```

Comment: R1 is only one object , I think and you are modifying using iteration , not creating a new radio button

Comment: `StringVar()` has methods `get()` and `set()`. So maybe you need `tvar.get()`.

Comment: always show full error message (Traceback), there are other useful infromation, ie. it shows which line of code makes problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I susspect you have problem in line (you didn't show full Traceback)

```
selection = "You selected the option " + tvar
```

You have to use `tvar.get()` to get value/string from `tvar`

```
selection = "You selected the option " + tvar.get()
```

Comment: A combination of `tvar = StringVar()` and `tvar.get()` seems to work.

Comment: with all classes `StringVar()`, `IntVar()`, `BoolenVar()`  you have to use `get()` and `set()` - More: [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htmhttp://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)